# Cannot view files and folders of Windows drive from Wubi

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I do not know what has gone wrong with my `D:` drive. The drive is absolutely fine, data is present.

I can unmount/mount the drive; but cannot view files and folders in it.
When I try to `ls` the drive from the terminal I get the following error:

```
ls: cannot access found.001: Input/output error
```

This was working fine till 2 days back, but it seems I have deleted some file.
Can someone please help figure out how can I view them again?

Wubi is installed in the `E:` drive.

Comment: getting error when ls:

`ls: cannot access found.001: Input/output error`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `chkdsk` from Windows. There appears to be some filesystem corruption and since it's `NTFS` you have to run it from Windows.

Boot Windows, open *My Computer*, right click on `D:`, Properties, Tools, Check disk for errors. That should clear it up.

Note that the `\found.???` directories are system protected and hidden by default and are used to recover corrupted files/directories.